# Pointers with c++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    int x=5,y=5;
    int sum = add(&x,&y);

    cout<<"Address of x is"<<&x<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of y is"<<&y<<endl;
    cout<<"The addition of a and b is"<<sum<<endl;

    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p1;
    p1=a;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"The Address of the Array elements is"<<p1+i<<endl;
        cout<<"The value of the array element is"<<*(p1+i)<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            cout<<"The Address of the Array elements is"<<&p1[i]<<endl;
            cout<<"The value of the array element is"<<p1[i]<<endl;
        }

    cout<<"address of a is "<<p1<<endl;
    int arrayTotal= SumofArray(a,5);
    cout<<"The sum of array is"<<arrayTotal <<endl;
}
```

I started to learn to code and I believe, I have to be strong with pointers to code in c++ and make efficient programs.

when we assign p1=a;

Literally i can use a[i] or p[i]? I am confused between this difference. The above snippet works tho I am curious if some one can explain in detail.

Thanks

Comment: Please before posting a question check whether it already exists or not otherwise by time you'll get blocked from posting.

Comment: _"... and I believe, I have to be strong with pointers to code in c++ and make efficient programs."_ No that's the completely wrong attitude to approach c++. You shouldn't deal with raw pointers or raw arrays in 1st place. There's c++ standard library support with `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: Being "strong with pointers" is **a lot** less important than beginners seem to think, at least in this millennium.

Comment: @Baum It's what their stupid teachers/professors want to see. I'm really pissed off to finance these people with my taxes paid.

Comment: Went with Unclear already, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/3002139) may be a good dupe target.

Comment: *I have to be strong with pointers to code in c++ and make efficient programs.* -- In a lot of situations, using pointers too much causes the compiler's optimizer to skip your code.  Thus the result is slower programs by overusing pointers, not more efficient ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Literally i can use `a[i]` or `p1[i]`?

Yes, dereferencing works the same way for a raw array symbol or a pointer.

The `a` symbol  in your example will decay to a `int*` pointer whenever used as such (`p1=a;`).

Using code like `p1[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(p1 +i)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear now. I have another question for you

Comment: @AmithRc If you have another question ask another question.